# Opencart product_id length more 9 symbols

Tags: opencart, product

I improt data from XML file to Opencart database. There are products with product_id more than 9 symbols long. I changed id_product data type from int(11) to bigint(20) in these columns:

oc_cart, oc_coupon_product, oc_customer_wishlist, oc_order_product, oc_order_recurring, oc_return, oc_review, oc_product, oc_product_attribute, oc_product_description, oc_product_discount, oc_product_filter, oc_product_image,
oc_product_option, oc_product_option_value, oc_product_recurring, oc_product_related, oc_product_reward, oc_product_special, oc_product_to_category, oc_product_to_download, oc_product_to_layout,
oc_product_to_store

I have these products in database, information there is correct. But, these products are empty on frontend and admin panel. Where else should I seek?

Thank you!

Comment: The product ID are always integers right?

Comment: Product IDs in my XML are numbers from 5 to 13 symbols.